# How to speed up the backup process of site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, backup

Is there any way I can speed up the backup process of a SharePoint site? I am trying with the `Backup-SPSite` PowerShell command

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

   ## SharePoint DLL 
   [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::
         LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 
     Backup-SPSite -Identity "http://srvr01:28516" -Path 
     "E:\Backups\srvr1_28516_file.bak"
```

I am having some 15 SharePoint 2013 workflows running in this site collection and some 8 item level event receivers and around 10+ JSOM coded forms created and deployed on this site as well.

Currently it's taking too much time to take a backup.

Comment: That looks normal to me, how big is your site collection in GBs ?  Is it greater 100 GB ?

Comment: its of <10 GB only... but it took more than 50 minutes to backup today...

Comment: Backup-SPSite is slow. Have you confirmed there are no bottlenecs in CPU, disk, or network if backing up to file share? Use DB backup is at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you Database supports it you can use the '-UseSqlSnapshot' with Backup-SPSite. I found it running faster, but be sure to have enough memory available otherwise the process may get stuck (I workaround the issue on 20GB site with increasing page file for the operation)

Comment: Please note that  -UseSqlSnapshot Does not support on SQL Standard edition.